# Generate html based on directory structure

Tags: linux, script

does any one knows a linux based program/script that can generate html files based on directory structure?

Comment: I made my own in python to index my Dropbox public folder. It wasn't very hard. (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/index.html if you want to see. The script that generated it is makeIndex2.py under /Python Scripts.)

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I can get the concept from your script.

Comment: @Phoshi, someone noted in a soon/now deleted answer: *"makeIndex2.py doesnt work because it uses a reserved word `with` that cannot be used in the way the script was written"*. That said, maybe you can post the script as an answer here? Links go dead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Some versions of [tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), which is a common utility, can produce HTML output.

```
tree -H baseHREF
```

Comment: I learn something new everyday here.

Comment: Hey Dennis Thanks a lot. Your answer is closest and easiest to deploy. I wasn't aware tree command is so powerful.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't available on the Windows tree command I have.

Comment: @jamiebarrow: The question is tagged [tag:linux].

Comment: Yes I know, hence 'Unfortunately' ... :) The -H switch isn't available for me, on Windows. I do have the tree command. I think via one of the GNU core utils packages.

Comment: I was looking for something like this though, for now I was just thinking of doing `tree /f /a>listing.txt` and take the output and write some custom tool to generate the HTML, but was hoping I could be lazy and not have to write that tool.

Comment: @jamiebarrow: Windows includes [its own tree command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tree.mspx?mfr=true). If you also have a GNU version, you should be able to upgrade to a version that supports `-H`.

Comment: For Mac OS
https://rschu.me/list-a-directory-with-tree-command-on-mac-os-x-3b2d4c4a4827

Comment: Huh, turns out all I needed was `-H` lmao